# Jenkinsfile: error with adding variables to shell commands

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This piece of code that I have is failing,

```
groovy_parameters ="""${params.is_destroy == true ? ' -destroy': ''} \
                                    -var 'client=${params.client}' \
                                    -var 'region=$region' \
                                    -var 'cluster=${params.cluster}' \
                                    -var 'vpc_name=${params.vpc}' \
                                    -var 'app_name=$app_name' \
                                    -var 'consul_url=${env.CONSUL_URL}' \
                                    -var 'kv_path=$consul_path' 
                                    """
                                    
                        
sh "${terraformBinaryName} import ${groovy_parameters} module.resources.aws_s3_bucket.antivirus_bucket[\"definitions\"] < bucket_name >"
```

with the jenkins executing:

> terraform1-29 import -var client=*** -var region=ap-southeast-2 -var cluster=*** -var vpc_name=*** -var app_name=*** -var consul_url=*** -var kv_path=***

So, it's adding all the `groovy_params` variable to the shell command but it's not adding the parts after it.

Which is why I get this terraform import error:

> The import command expects two arguments.

Any help on fixing this would be appreciated!

Edit: adding screenshot from Jenkins:
[image]

Comment: Can you check if the other missing part is moving to next line

Comment: Yeah checked, it isn't.. added a screenshot to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra newline character in the end of the `groovy_parameters` variable. This newline character splits the command so that `sh` step thinks that parameters after `groovy_parameters` are a new separate command. The separate command is not visible in console output because Jenkins by default uses [`-xe` shell flags](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) in `sh` steps and thus stops executing commands on first failing command.

Either add `\` to the last row of the multi-line string or end the multi-line string before the last new line character:

```
groovy_parameters ="""${params.is_destroy == true ? ' -destroy': ''} \
    -var 'client=${params.client}' \
    -var 'region=$region' \
    -var 'cluster=${params.cluster}' \
    -var 'vpc_name=${params.vpc}' \
    -var 'app_name=$app_name' \
    -var 'consul_url=${env.CONSUL_URL}' \
    -var 'kv_path=$consul_path'"""
```